# Radio button change handler refreshing the page

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm using UploadItem, RadioGroupItem and some other widgets. RadioButton is having onChangeHandler which will decide what all other components need to be displayed. I've uploaded some file using UploadItem. Then I changed the radio button selection. On changing the radio button, required widgets are getting displayed properly but whatever file I'd selected using UploadItem is going away. Fresh UploadItem widget is getting displayed. In other words page is getting refreshed. 
My requirement is whenever I change radio button option, required widget should displayed along with that whatever file I had selected using UploadItem should remain same.
My Code is something like this:

```
UploadItem upload = new UploadItem();
RadioGroupItem radioGroup = new RadioGroupItem();
HashMap map = new HashMap();
map.put("option1","option1");
map.put("option2","option2");
radioGroup.setValueMap(map);
TextItem textbox = new TextItem();
radioGroup.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler(){
          public void onChanged(ChangedEvent event) {  

                   String radioValue =((String)event.getValue());  
                  if(radioValue.equalsIgnoreCase("option2")){

                          textbox.show();

                  }else{
                            textbox.hide();
                  }
          }
});
```

Add all created widgets to DynamicForm object using dynamicForm.setFields(all created widgets)
Changing the radio button should hide and show the textBox. But while doing that page is getting refreshed and whatever file we had selected using UploadItem is lost.

Comment: Added code sample in question

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation for [hide()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/FormItem.html#hide%28%29) and [show()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/FormItem.html#show%28%29) of FormItem class, invocation of any of these methods, will cause the DynamicForm to be redrawn.

So it may cause the problem you're getting.

To overcome this issue, I would suggest you to put UploadItem in a separate DynamicForm.

Answer (score 0):

fire an event on radio Selection change as

```
  radioButton.addListener(Events.Change, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {
            if(radioButton.getValue()){
                //fire an event here for ur widget
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Swamy I have done editing in the question and give the code sample. Please check.